# Woocommerce permalink substr replace

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, permalinks

I have been searching and trying different solutions for about 2 weeks. I am about to give up, but first i want to ask for your help.

The permalink on my site is like this [www.mysite.com/productsku](http://www.mysite.com/productsku)

All the products skus are like ABC1234, three letters followed by four numbers

Now, the solution i am searching is that when someone enters on their webaddress [www.mysite.com/1200](http://www.mysite.com/1200) they will be automatically redirected to the real address which is [www.mysite.com/dna1200](http://www.mysite.com/dna1200)

I tried adding a second permalink, but no luck, as there is now way around it.

I tried some regex, but no luck either.

Do you have any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Can you add this to your question: When user inserts this: ???? into browser it should redirect him to this ????.
Please fill in the question marks so we can understand what should happen.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding you want to match the url's path and redirect it to the corresponding sku. The part you're missing is that you'd need to perform a lookup in what I'm assuming a database that is holding this information and return the sku.

Here's the regex to match the numerical part that you're after.

```
^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/(\d{4})$
```

- `^` Start of a string
- `http` `s?` Matches *http* and zero or one instance of *s*, respectively.
- `:\/\/` Matches a colon and two forward slashes *://*
- `[^\/]+` Matches all non forward slash characters (this matches the domain name)
- `\/` Matches the first slash indicating the start of the url's path
- `(` Start of capture group, the part of interest

  - `\d{4}` Four digit characters
- `)` End of capture group
- `$` End of string

Comment: Truly thanks Bren.  So, you say to include this regex in the .htaccess file!?  I am a noob, so every bit of info helps me.  So if my website is supercats.com, the regex needs to look like ^https?:\/\/[^www.SuperCats.com\/]+\/(\d{4})$.  ?  That.s it?

Comment: @selfmade Unless every sku starts with `dna` then you would need to perform a lookup in your database to get the prefix. Also, the `[^\/]+` part is just an abstract means of matching the domain name so the pattern is more flexible.